# Is there a T1 or faction frigate that can solo a Dramiel?

Tags: eve-online

Dramiels are annoying when you're flying around alone, ships that do enough damage and tank enough to kill them often don't have enough range control to prevent the Dramiel from escaping.

Now, if I have a predictable enemy Dramiel pilot that flies a dual-prop Dramiel with complex MWD & AB, scram, 200mm Autocannons and a rocket launcher and T2 shield rigs and Warrior drones. It can put out around 130 dps with the autocannons and 50 from the 3 drones, it has roughly 8k EHP and can fly at least 1700 m/s on AB.

Is there any navy faction or T1 frigate (not pirate) that could kill this Dramiel? My idea would be an armor-tanked, dual-web Hookbill with a tracking disruptor, keeping the Dramiel at the edge of scram-range. What are the weaknesses of the Dramiel that I could exploit, and which ships would be suited to that task?

Answer (score 1):

Exact fit I don't have, but, to quote [*The Altruist*](http://www.evealtruist.com/2011/07/know-your-enemy-faction-frigates.html):

> The hookbill is known to be one of the few ships which can consistently kill a dramiel without it simply being able to burn away, and against any blaster ship (other than potentially the daredevil) a dual web hookbill is likely to walk through the fight with relative ease.

Answer (score 1):

Might switch a couple of modules around ( if you really want to use an ASB over the armor buffer ), but [this](http://eve.battleclinic.com/loadout/61058-Caldari-Navy-Hookbill-CN-Hookbill-Twin-Webs-TD-and-Plated.html) is a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

There's no general answer for this, but yes it is possible, especially if the Dramiel pilot is making mistakes.

Just recently I've seen [this kill](http://killfeed.eveuniversity.org/?a=kill_detail&kll_id=52853) on kill boards.

As for weaknesses, IMO it's all about the Dramiel's Speed (actually being it's advantage as well):

- Even with some tank it relies heavily on being too fast to being hit (speed/signature tanking).
- It needs a lot of tracking itself to shoot back and hit as well.

With these point in mind, your idea isn't that bad at all:

- Slow the Dramiel down (Stasis Webifier), making it easier to hit.
- Improve your own tracking (Tracking Enhancer/Tracking Computer/ammo choice/weapon choice/ship choice) also making it easier to hit.
- Lower the Dramiel's tracking (Tracking Disruptor), forcing it to move slower or hit for less damage.
- Increase its Signature Radius (Target Painter; far less effective, if barely noticeable; the Shield Rigs will do this for you, too) - also pointless, in case it's using the MWD.

However, I have to disagree with one of your ideas:

- Keeping the Dramiel at the Edge of your Warp Scrambler's range will be very tricky, even webbed the Dramiel might have enough speed to break free if you're too far on the "edge".

Answer (score 1):

My CEO actually has accomplished this task

http://eve-kill.net/?a=kill_detail&kll_id=15572902

We attempted to recreate the situation on Sisi the other day, and we determined several things must have factored into this.

1) Marcel was in a faction warfare plex, which means he knew exactly where the dram would land. The hardest part about fighting a Dram with a tristan is just catching the thing. Given that the Dram landed on him, he could web and scram the dram, and mitigate a fair chunk of their advantage.

2) The pilot had to have made some errors. Perhaps he didn't realize what to do one he WAS actually caught, but likely he did not overheat his weapon system.

3) Marcel is a fantastic manual pilot, and was able to out fly the not-as-good dram pilot, all the while his drones picking at him.

In practice, it took two Tristans to get the dram down if we just sat toe to toe and slugged him. Chances are you will need to outkite the dram, which would take a good kiting ship (such as that Merlin in the other answer), but mostly a ton of player skill.

Thankfully, not all Dram pilots are skilled, many of them just think that they are automatic win, and so fly them poorly.